# Why is async causing issues in my javascript?

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js

Can anyone tell me why `async: false;` doesn't allow my spinner to display during data load?
But when I used `async: true;` it reverses my default display toggle?

I currently have list set up with 5 different items. 3 of those items are set up to display by default when the page loads. Then they can be clicked off or the other 2 items can be clicked on. When I use `async: true;` to get my spinner to display, its like it doesn't recognize the default toggles. Even though they are selected on page load, the information does not display. It only displays after they are UNselected.

```
$(function () {
        var HistoryViewModel;
        var xspinner = new Spinner();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Users/GetAccountHistory',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: { accountId: @Model.Account.AccountID },
            beforeSend: function () {
                xspinner.showSpinner("Getting History Information...");
            },
            complete: function () {
                xspinner.hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                HistoryViewModel = new RCM.ViewModels.History.HistoryViewModel(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
                ko.applyBindings(HistoryViewModel, document.getElementById('ListPanel'));
                ko.applyBindings(HistoryViewModel, document.getElementById("DetailsPanel"));
                ie9HeightFix();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                notify.show({ type: 'error', header: 'Error!', content: 'Error fetching History, ' + xhr.statusText });
                return false;
            }
        });
        function ie9HeightFix() {
            if(document.addEventListener && !window.requestAnimationFrame) 
            { 
                var eTop = $('.AccountHx').offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
                var dTop = eTop - $(window).scrollTop(); //position of the ele w.r.t window
                var cHeight = $(window).height() - dTop - $(".colophon").height();
                $(".AccountHx").css("height", cHeight);
                $(".AccountHx").css("position", "relative");
                $(".AccountHx").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
                $(".AccountHx-detailsPanel").css("left", "32rem");
                $(".viewDetailsButton").css("right", "2rem");
            }
        }
        $(window).resize(function() {
            ie9HeightFix();
        });
        $("#vToggle").click();
        $("#pToggle").click();
        $("#sToggle").click();
        $(".search-button").click(function(event){
            $(".subHeader").toggleClass("search-visible");
            $(".AccountHx-items").toggleClass("search-visible");
            $(".search-button").toggleClass("search-visible");
        });
        $(".filter-button, .modal-close").click(function(event){
            $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel").toggleClass("filters-visible");
            $(".filter-birdBeak").toggle();
        });
        $(".filterButtons input").attr("disabled", false);
    });

    $("#vToggle").click(function(){
        $(".js-vItem").toggle();
        $("#vToggle").toggleClass("is-active");
    });
    $("#cToggle").click(function(){
        $(".js-claimItem").toggle();
        $("#cToggle").toggleClass("is-active");
    });
    $("#nToggle").click(function(){
        $(".js-nItem").toggle();
        $("#nToggle").toggleClass("is-active");
    });
    $("#sToggle").click(function(){
        $(".js-sItem").toggle();
        $("#sToggle").toggleClass("is-active");
    });
    $("#pToggle").click(function(){
        $(".js-pItem").toggle();
        $("#pToggle").toggleClass("is-active");
    });
    $("li.filterButton").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings(".clearButton").show();
        $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel .clearButton--all").css('display', 'inline-block');
    });
    $(".clearButton").click(function(){
        var hiddenOption = $(this).siblings(".filterButtons").children(".hiddenOption");
        hiddenOption.siblings('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
        hiddenOption.toggleClass("is-active");
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel .clearButton--all").click(function() {
        $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel .filterButton").removeClass("is-active");
        $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel .hiddenOption").toggleClass("is-active");
        $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel .filterCheckbox").attr('checked', false);
        $(".AccountHx-filtersPanel .clearButton").hide();
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

Comment: Can you include a working code sample and simplify the code included to be a small as possible (ie don't include unrelated js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I discovered is to move the 
`$("#visitToggle").click();
 $("#paymentToggle").click();
 $("#statementToggle").click();`

inside the following section 
`success: function (data) {...}`

and change `async` to `true`